# Translating raster from floating point to int16 increases size

Tags: pyqgis, gdal-translate, floating-point, integer

I know that floating point takes 4 bytes and signed integer 16 takes 2 bytes.
I have many DEM .tif rasters, they are all of type floating32.
I want to convert them to type integer16 (regardless of loss in value accuracy from -0.5 to +0.5).
I used this command:

```
processing.run("gdal:translate", {'INPUT':'C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Data/europa/Copernicus_DSM_COG_10_N27_00_W016_00_DEM.tif','TARGET_CRS':None,'NODATA':-9999,'COPY_SUBDATASETS':False,'OPTIONS':'','EXTRA':'','DATA_TYPE':2,'OUTPUT':'C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Data/europa_int/Copernicus_DSM_COG_10_N27_00_W016_00_DEM.tif'})
```

My original rasters have differents sizes from ca 5Mb to 40Mb but after translating them, it seems that those which had 5 Mb become 25.34Mb (so increasing in size) and those which had 40Mb become the same fixed size 25.34Mb (so decreasing in size).

Can anyone explain me this behavior, why they will NOT at least be the half size of the original because 4-byte is twice 2-byte in size?

**EDIT**
Metadata of a small size raster:

```
Extent  -32.0001388888888911,39.0001388888888911 : -31.0001388888888911,40.0001388888888911
Width   3600
Height  3600
Data type   Float32 - Thirty two bit floating point
GDAL Driver Description GTiff
GDAL Driver Metadata    GeoTIFF
Dataset Description C:\Users\admin\Downloads\Copernicus_DSM_COG_10_N39_00_W032_00_DEM.tif
Compression DEFLATE
Band 1  
STATISTICS_APPROXIMATE=YES
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=880.71441650391
STATISTICS_MEAN=6.5788498616515
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
STATISTICS_STDDEV=57.129060472332
STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
Scale: 1
Offset: 0
More information    
AREA_OR_POINT=Point
X : 1800
Y : 1800
X : 900
Y : 900
X : 450
Y : 450
Dimensions  X: 3600 Y: 3600 Bands: 1
Origin  -32.0001388888888911,40.0001388888888911
Pixel Size  0.0002777777777777777775,-0.0002777777777777777775
```

Metadata of a large size raster:

```
Extent  -5.0001388888888885,40.0001388888888911 : -4.0001388888888885,41.0001388888888911
Width   3600
Height  3600
Data type   Float32 - Thirty two bit floating point
GDAL Driver Description GTiff
GDAL Driver Metadata    GeoTIFF
Dataset Description C:\Users\admin\Downloads\Copernicus_DSM_COG_10_N40_00_W005_00_DEM_2.tif
Compression DEFLATE
Band 1  
STATISTICS_APPROXIMATE=YES
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=2159.1462402344
STATISTICS_MEAN=923.07085519958
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=372.08935546875
STATISTICS_STDDEV=332.30329174664
STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
Scale: 1
Offset: 0
More information    
AREA_OR_POINT=Point
X : 1800
Y : 1800
X : 900
Y : 900
X : 450
Y : 450
Dimensions  X: 3600 Y: 3600 Bands: 1
Origin  -5.0001388888888885,41.0001388888888911
Pixel Size  0.0002777777777777777775,-0.0002777777777777777775
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your 5 Mb inputs are compressed and your outputs are not.

Your 40 Mb inputs may be compressed, but didn't compress well (very noisy data leads to poor compression, a random raster can actually compress to larger than the uncompressed original) or are compressed and have overviews.

Try compressing when you translate with:

```
'OPTIONS':'COMPRESS=LZW|PREDICTOR=2|ZLEVEL=9'
# Or
'OPTIONS':'COMPRESS=DEFLATE|PREDICTOR=2|ZLEVEL=9'

# Example
processing.run("gdal:translate", {'INPUT':'C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Data/europa/Copernicus_DSM_COG_10_N27_00_W016_00_DEM.tif','TARGET_CRS':None,'NODATA':-9999,'COPY_SUBDATASETS':False,'OPTIONS':'COMPRESS=DEFLATE|PREDICTOR=2|ZLEVEL=9','EXTRA':'','DATA_TYPE':2,'OUTPUT':'C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Data/europa_int/Copernicus_DSM_COG_10_N27_00_W016_00_DEM.tif'})
```

You should always inspect your data (and post details here when asking questions!) by looking at the QGIS layer properties - information tab, using the Raster Information processing tool, or running `gdalinfo yourraster` from a command prompt.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, compression is deflate.
I added the metadata for both rasters, one with small size and the other with large size.